# Как можно в код php вставить возможность перезагрузить страничку.

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, нельзя ли как-нибудь по условию if  в php код  вставить указание страничке перезагузиться в первоначальный вид.
Нужно для случая . если юзер ввел что-то не то при авторизации, и сессия создана , но пуста, вернуть ему возможность опять заполнить форму . Как-то может туда Logout вставить?

Comment: Существование сессии не должно быть признаком авторизации, а logout не должен быть реализован как удаление сессии. Сделайте проверку авторизации по содержимому сессии, а logout как чистку (но не удаление!) сессии — проблема отпадёт сама собой

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но только я его не поняла к сожалению.Она у меня и не есть признак авторизации. Ее пустота- это признак не авторизации. Я никак не могу по пустоте сессии , когда юзер неправильно ввел данные и в бд они не найдены, вернуть страничке первоначальный вид.

Comment: @Masha, а зачем вы создаете сессию, если юзер не правильно ввел логин/пароль?

Comment: я не хочу сессию удалять, я хочу страничке вернуть прежний вид.

Comment: она сама создается в самом верху php. на тот случай если все пойдет как надо и туда можно будет записать идентификацию юзера

Comment: Тогда я не понял, что мешает вернуть страничке прежний вид, если не сессия?

Comment: @Masha, сделайте редирект на первоначальную страницу с использованием `header("Location ...` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: извините, я новичок в этом деле, а разве не наптсано везде что header можно ставить только в самом верху?

Comment: @Masha, его можно использовать до того, как вы начали выводить данные пользователю. Если вы обрабатываете данные пришедшие из формы, то выводить результат будете после обработки. Если обработка нашла ошибку, то вы можете отправить заголовок на переадресацию, так как ни каких данных пользователю еще не отдавали.

Comment: Действительно ,отлично получилось!

Comment: Большое спасибо :)